# AJAX form post request refreshes the page Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am working on this registration form: https://www.redmineup.com/pages/cloud/registration

It is an AJAX form that sends a post request to a server. It works perfectly fine on mozilla and chrome but not in Internet Explorer. The page just gets refreshed after clicking the submit button. I am thinking it's something to do with e.preventDefault(), I read that it isn't supported in IE, but using e.returnValue = false, doesn't work aswell. Please view the page source and tell me if you have any ideas. I have not worked with Internet Explorer compatibility before.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me which version of IE you are seeing the issue?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 is the one installed on my machine, my co-workers also had problems, not sure what version they are using.

Comment: You have an error of some kind which aborts running the handler function and instead the default action occurs.  I would guess that your use of `URL()` is the problem as that is [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility).  You should probably get your hands on an IE that fails and check the error console.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and i found that, you are not using the form's native features like **action**="someEndPoint" and **method**="Get/post etc".

By default when a submit  button is present in the form and is clicked on, it will trigger the native action of the form i.e perform the get/post call and refresh the page.

So, instead of using

```
<input type="submit" id="submitForm">
```

try using

```
<input type="button" id="submitForm">
```

and then attach a click listener to it in your jquery code like below

```
$('submitForm').click(function(){
  // your ajax call goes here
});
```